# Python turns np.array into a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to create a `np.array` in the following way:

```
A = np.array([
              [56,0, 0.0, 4.4, 68.0],
              [1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0],
              [1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9]])

print(A)
```

But my output is this:

```
[list([56, 0, 0.0, 4.4, 68.0]) list([1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0])
 list([1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9])]
```

Due to this, I can't use functions like `reshape`.  I don't understand why its causing this problem.

Comment: Numpy arrays are true multidimensional arrays. your first list has 5 it's, the rest has 4. What shape do you expect the resulting array to be?

Comment: You wrote `56,0` instead of `56.0`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output

```
[list([56, 0, 0.0, 4.4, 68.0]) list([1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0])
 list([1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9])]
```

is the correct output.

```
type(A) # outputs <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I have tried `print(np.reshape(A, (1, -1)))` which outputs

```
array([[list([56, 0, 0.0, 4.4, 68.0]), list([1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0]),
        list([1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9])]], dtype=object)
```

I think something else is causing your problem. So please show us the full error message.